# SelectedIndex for all ComboBox elements

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to set the SelectedIndex for all ComboBox's in a C# Windows Form?

I have tried this:

```
foreach (ComboBox cb in Controls)
{
    cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

But does not seem to work.

Comment: The problem might be with the Controls collection.  This is a collection of controls that are parented by the form directly.  In practice you combos may be nested further down, e.g. in group boxes.

Comment: This is good example of case when explicit use of control is more maintainable/readable. Set it manually to all comboboxes or at least create custom collection of comboboxes and use this collection for setting default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Control cnl in Controls)
{
    if(cnl is ComboBox)
    {
       ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)cnl;
       cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: This did the trick thanks. I like it as well due to being a simple and easy way.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: if not all controls are `ComboBox` then it will fail with an `InvalidCastException`. First and most simple *trick* is to consider only `ComboBox`:

```
foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
    cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

---

**Longer answer**: note that this will fail if you have a tree of controls. You may want to write an extension method Descendants() to be used like this:

```
foreach (var cb in Descendants().OfType<ComboBox>())
    cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Where a possible implementation is something similar to this untested one:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> Descendants(this Control control)
{
    yield return control;

    var descendants = control.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(x => Descendants(x));
    foreach (var descendant in descendants)
        yield return descendant;
}
```

---

**Note**: however note that it's probably not best solution on long-term, you should mark those comboboxes somehow or databind them and work on (View) Model instead directly manipulating UI controls.

Answer (score 1):

Add a function like this:

```
private void SetComboIndex(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if(c is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)c;
            cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        SetComboIndex(c);
    }
}
```

and call it like this from the form:

```
SetComboIndex(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all item in Controls are Combo boxes.
use this:

```
foreach (var control in Controls)
{
    if (control is ComboBox)
        ((ComboBox)control).SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```